# Why is my python Slack app running forever with nothing happening?

Tags: slack-api

I have followed the [Slack API tutorial](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/blob/master/tutorial/04-running-the-app.md) on making a Python slackclient bot. Now I have reached the last step, which is to run `app.py`.

The problem is that it runs forever and nothing happens

Both the `ssl_context` and the `slack_token` prints to something sensible: 
`xoxb-XXXXXXXXXXXX-xxxxxxxxxxxx-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` and 
`<ssl.SSLContext object at 0x00000xxxxxxxxxxx>`

The .start() method including the fetching of the client and tokens looks like this (including printing the values):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ssl_context = ssl_lib.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
    slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]
    rtm_client = slack.RTMClient(token=slack_token, ssl=ssl_context)
    print ("ssl = %s" % ssl_context)
    print ("Token = %s" % slack_token)
    rtm_client.start()
```

*The rest of the files is reachable through the tutorial link on the top*.

When pressing Ctrl+C, I get the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 133, in <module>
    rtm_client.start()
  File "C:\Users\anna.jenssen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\slack\rtm\client.py", line 198, in start
    return self._event_loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Users\anna.jenssen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 595, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\anna.jenssen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 316, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\anna.jenssen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 563, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\anna.jenssen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1808, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\anna.jenssen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 430, in select
    self._poll(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\anna.jenssen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 779, in _poll
    status = _overlapped.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(self._iocp, ms)
KeyboardInterrupt
^C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the RTM Client is meant to run forever as it's job is to listen for events in your channel.

If you want to see what the RTM Client is doing, you can add the below to your main:

```
# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# set how logger will format logs
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# add formatting to logger
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

ssl_context = ssl_lib.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
rtm_client = slack.RTMClient(token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN, ssl=ssl_context)
rtm_client.start()
```

Don't forget to `import logging` as well in your py file.

Then you'll be able to see it initialising and responding to events. The below is an example of me starting the RTM Client and sending a message in the channel that the bot has been added to:

```
   2019-10-20 13:11:15,456 - DEBUG - Using selector: SelectSelector
   2019-10-20 13:11:15,458 - DEBUG - Retrieving websocket info.
   2019-10-20 13:11:20,052 - DEBUG - The Websocket connection has been opened.
   2019-10-20 13:11:20,296 - DEBUG - Running 1 callbacks for event: 'message'
```

Hope that helps.

Also, on a side note, you might want to edit your question and remove the bot token as anyone would be able to use it to listen to messages your sending in your channel.